# rustc weirdly assuming that type parameters have to be the same even when they're separate?

Tags: types, rust

I'm working on a library that requires as part of its functionality comparison between different types based on a key contained within them.

There is no way to require that the keys are the same in stable Rust (can't use equality bounds), so I'm using PartialOrd even though the keys are required to be Ord. Because of this requirement, it's safe to unwrap the result of `partial_cmp()` (it must be `Some` by specification).

However, with this bound, Rust seems to give up trying to resolve the associated type `Key` and whether it has `PartialOrd` with the other key, and just assumes that the types must be the same:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:60:29
   |
60 |     let order = compare(&a, &b);
   |                             ^^ expected struct `TypeA`, found struct `TypeB`
   |
   = note: expected type `&TypeA`
              found type `&TypeB`
```

In my much more complex example, where Keyed has another type parameter that determines the sort method (to allow for flexibility), the error I get looks like this:

```
can't compare `<types::test_helpers::TestObject as types::Keyed<'a, types::test_helpers::SortFirst>>::Key` with `<i32 as types::Keyed<'a, types::test_helpers::SortFirst>>::Key`
```

even though the associated type `Key` for both is just `i32`. This maybe provides more clarity into where the compiler is having a problem. The other errors before that seem to end up assuming that the types should be the same, just like in the little example I'm including.

Here is a minimal reproducible example ([link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=351ca831006058fd4f3ec18f43caecdf)):

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

trait Keyed<'a> {
    type Key: 'a + Eq + Ord;

    fn key(&'a self) -> Self::Key;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct TypeA {
    key: (i32, i32),
    value: String,
}

impl<'a> Keyed<'a> for TypeA {
    type Key = (&'a i32, &'a i32);

    fn key(&'a self) -> (&'a i32, &'a i32) {
        (&self.key.0, &self.key.1)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct TypeB {
    key_a: i32,
    key_b: i32,
    value: u64,
}

impl<'a> Keyed<'a> for TypeB {
    type Key = (&'a i32, &'a i32);

    fn key(&'a self) -> (&'a i32, &'a i32) {
        (&self.key_a, &self.key_b)
    }
}

fn compare<A, B>(a: &A, b: &B) -> Ordering
where
    for<'a> A: Keyed<'a>,
    for<'a> B: Keyed<'a>,
    for<'a> <A as Keyed<'a>>::Key: Ord,
    for<'a> <B as Keyed<'a>>::Key: Ord,
    for<'a> <A as Keyed<'a>>::Key: PartialOrd<<B as Keyed<'a>>::Key>,
{
    a.key().partial_cmp(&b.key()).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let a = TypeA {
        key: (3, 4),
        value: "Hello!".into(),
    };

    let b = TypeB {
        key_a: 3,
        key_b: 5,
        value: 9292,
    };

    let order = compare(&a, &b);

    println!("{:?}.key() = {:?}", a, a.key());
    println!("{:?}.key() = {:?}", b, b.key());
    println!("compare({:?}, {:?}) = {:?}", a, b, order);

    assert_eq!(order, Ordering::Less);
}
```

Anyone who has experience with how rustc does type calculus or who has had a similar problem have any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Firstly, neither `Key` is an `i32` in your gist. Both are `(&'a i32, &'a i32)` tuples, where the lifetime comes from the relevant parent struct type. And what I think is happening here is `TypeA::Key` and `TypeB::Key` are being treated as different types, instead of both being aliases for `(&'a i32, &'a i32)`, so the only `PartialOrd` implementation that is visible is `PartialOrd<Self>`, which causes the compiler to look for another `TypeA`. This is more easier to figure out if you explicitly specify the type parameters to `compare()`.

Comment: The rust HRTB seems to be in fault here. If your `compare` function is declared as `fn compare<'a, 'b, A, B>(a: &'a A, b: &'b B) -> Ordering`, whole thing compiles. Could be a known [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56556), too. But the errors aren't exactly the same, so I'm not sure. Does the same workaround work for your real code?

Comment: @IskarJarak Apologies, it's `i32` in the real code, but I was trying to use an example that would demonstrate what I was going for in terms of flexibility.

@edwardw The reason why I can't do that in the real code is that I'm actually working with Streams, and making stream adaptors. The lifetimes for the objects coming out of the streams can't be based on the context of the impl because the stream passes ownership of objects it produces - a HRTB is really necessary here, I believe.

Comment: While the error here is interesting, [when `Key` doesn't contain a reference this is easy to solve](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a8e67d839f28269d1f2d4f3361b14c6), so there might be another question buried in your actual problem that the minimal example doesn't demonstrate.

Comment: devyn, Please excuse the nitpick re Key type.
Re. what @edwardw said regarding the error message not being an exact match to the issue he linked, I believe your problem really is the same as that bug - a few small modifications of your gist produce the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a workaround. By providing the following trait and being *very* specific about which types need to be comparable, you can avoid what I assume to be a Rust bug about evaluating HRTB associated types. It may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56556) as noted by @edwardw.

This trait does work fine with HRTBs as long as you use the exact types that you require to be comparable in your bounds. I'm thinking this workaround may be applicable to some other cases of that bug too.

```
pub trait KeyedCmp<'a, B>: Keyed<'a> where B: Keyed<'a> {
    fn keyed_cmp(&'a self, other: &'a B) -> Ordering;
}

impl<'a, A, B> KeyedCmp<'a, B> for A
    where A: Keyed<'a>,
          B: Keyed<'a>,
          <A as Keyed<'a>>::Key: PartialOrd<<B as Keyed<'a>>::Key> {

    fn keyed_cmp(&'a self, other: &'a B) -> Ordering {
        self.key().partial_cmp(&other.key()).unwrap()
    }
}
```